# iPhone: Downloading zip and extracting in main bundle subdirectory at runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to extend my iPhone app that the app downloads a zip file into 
a sub directory then extracts it and then load images which were inside the zip.

Any ideas how to unzip in run-time and the access the images? Would be really happy for some idea.

Greetings,

Comment: Main bundle is read-only. You can't extract a file to it, however you could use a local directory like the documents directory.

Answer (score 20):

I've used [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/) with success in the past.

It's pretty ligthweight and simple to use, supports password protection, multiple files inside a ZIP, as well as compress & decompress.

The basic usage is:

```
NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ZipFileName" ofType:@"zip"];
ZipArchive *zipArchive = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
[zipArchive UnzipOpenFile:filepath Password:@"xxxxxx"];
[zipArchive UnzipFileTo:{pathToDirectory} overWrite:YES];
[zipArchive UnzipCloseFile];
[zipArchive release];
```

Comment: how to check if the file is password protected or not, does it support that

Comment: This is based on obj C++, can I get Obj C version so that I don't have  to use OBJ C++ compiler?

Comment: @Rog can I use ZipArchive for ios 6

Comment: I couldn't get my app to build with this, I am adding libz.1.2.5.dylib but it's not running, which frameworks are you importing ?

Answer (score 9):

You cannot extract into your bundle. Use `[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]` to get the path to a directory you can write to.

You can use the code from http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/ to extract files from the zip archive.

Comment: can I use Ziparchive for ios 6

Answer (score 3):

If you add `ZipArchive` to your project, remember to also add the framework.
The correct framework is `libz.dylib`. **Latest version (Xcode 4.2) is 1.2.5**.

(Add framework to the section with libraries in the build phases tab of your target.)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use [ssziparchive](https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive) bcoz it support both `ARC` and `Non ARC` project.

1. Add `SSZipArchive.h`, `SSZipArchive.m`, and `minizip` to your project.
2. Add latest version of the `libz`(right now its `libz1.2.5`) library to your target.

You don't need to do anything regarding `ARC`. `SSZipArchive` will detect if you're not using `ARC` and add the required memory management code.

And code will be like this:

```
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

    // Unzipping

    //If your zip is in document directory than use this code
    NSString *zipPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mediadata.zip"];
    //else if zip file is in bundle than use this code
    NSString *zipPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mediadata" ofType:@"zip"];

    NSString *destinationPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MediaData"];


    if( [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath] != NO ) {
        //unzip data success
        //do something
        NSLog(@"Dilip Success");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Dilip Error");
    }
```

Comment: If ".zip" file in server, how to use SSZipArchive library. Please let us know

Comment: @JoshKethepalli in this case you have to download ZIP file first in the local and than extract it, Without original ZIP file in local storage there is no way you can extract it.

Comment: When i m extracting the file it shows ".dat" format. How to extract the file same like as normal folder

Comment: @JoshKethepalli Can you check you zip, that its not corrupted after download.