# How to un-gzip file received from server on iPhone?

Tags: ios, gzip, nsurlconnection

I am using NSURLConnection to download gzipped JSON from server. Is it possible to un-gzip received data with libraries that are part of iOS (Cocoa touch framework)?
I am somehow confused since a lot of people are pointing me to download some third party libraries?

Comment: I have the same discovery.The .tar.gz file downloaded by NSSession is actually  a tar file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know for sure if there is built-in iOS functionality for this, but I know that a solid approach is to use [ZipArchive](http://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/).  Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/412982/iphone-unzip-code), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385480/iphone-downloding-zip-and-extracting-in-main-bundle-subdirectory-at-runtime).

Comment: Is ZipArchive also for gzip, not only for zip?