# Archiving on iOS using NSKeyedArchiver

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, zip, nskeyedarchiver

I'd like my app to decompress and handle the contents of zip files.

I'm trying to do this the Cocoa way, without using external libraries, so I'm turning to [`NSKeyedUnarchiver`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSKeyedUnarchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and here's my code:

```
-(void) unarchive{

    NSString *outputDirectory = [[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingString:@"/Documents/"] stringByAppendingString:@"TheNewFolderName/"];
    NSLog(@"Output Directory: %@", outputDirectory);

    //MyArchive.zip is the filename of the zip file I placed in Xcode
    NSData *theArchive = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:@"MyArchive.zip"];

    NSError *error;
    [theArchive writeToFile:outputDirectory options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

    NSLog(@"theArchive is %@", theArchive);
```

And this prints "theArchive is null"! What am I doing wrong..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` are used for archiving and unarchiving objects (NSObject subclasses, with certain restrictions) in your application. I'm afraid you cannot use it with zip files.

Comment: Indeed... This works for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385480/iphone-downloding-zip-and-extracting-in-main-bundle-subdirectory-at-runtime
But... So the only way to decompress a zip file at runtime is to use a third-party library?