# Store file like .rar or zip in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7

I am new in iOS and want to Know that Is there any way to store file in app like a .rar or zip file and extract files when required.

Comment: You have 2 questions here: Storing files and extract files. Yes, you can store files in iOS App. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6029916/how-to-enable-file-sharing-for-my-app). For extracting files, there are tons of tutorials online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using **ZipArchive**

Here is the complete tutorial for zip and unzip file.

http://transoceanic.blogspot.in/2011/07/compressuncompress-files-on.html

**Uncompress zip file example:**

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *zipFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myZipFileName.zip"];

NSString *output = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"unZipDirName"];

ZipArchive* za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

if( [za UnzipOpenFile:zipFilePath] ) {
    if( [za UnzipFileTo:output overWrite:YES] != NO ) {
        //unzip data success
        //do something
    }

    [za UnzipCloseFile];
}

[za release];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/detail?name=ZipArchive.zip), a private third party class to archive and extract the file.

And, the usage of [ZipArchive](https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/detail?name=ZipArchive.zip) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385480/iphone-downloding-zip-and-extracting-in-main-bundle-subdirectory-at-runtime).

Comment: Thanks But Also tell me that Is this a good way to store file in app in this way like Videos or images etc.

Comment: Ofcourse, you could archive the file(an image or a video) and store that in documents folder of your app. But, your app may have the possibility to consume more memory in future times as usage of the app goes on.